# Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I am new in angular 5 development. I am trying to develop a data table with angular material using the example provided here: "https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples".

I am getting an error saying `Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.`

[image]

Please help.

Comment: It's not `table`, just use `<mat-table #table [dataSource]...>`

Comment: tried using the mat-table tag, then error disappears but I don't see my table in the view.

Comment: That's the right way to use the element, you must have other problems somewhere else

Comment: Can you provide me a working example using `mat-table` tag?

Comment: also, I exactly copied the code. No change in `ts` and `html` code.

Comment: what version of material are you using? The material table selector is different between v5 and v6.

Comment: "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
`    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5"`

Comment: The selector that you are using is from v6, and you have installed v5. You should take a look at the v5 examples https://v5.material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: table is created but sorting is not working

Comment: Got the solution. I forgot to add the MatSortModule in app.module.ts.

Comment: @RahulMunjal: If you don't mind, you could add your solution (if it works as expected) as answer, so that other users could benefit of it... this is the main target of STO.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Thanx to @Jota.Toledo, I got the solution for my table creation.
Please find the working code below:

***component.html***

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.id}}" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.value}}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.id]}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

***component.ts***

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-m',
  templateUrl: './m.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./m.component.css'],
})
export class MComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = [];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  /**
   * Pre-defined columns list for user table
   */
  columnNames = [{
    id: 'position',
    value: 'No.',

  }, {
    id: 'name',
    value: 'Name',
  },
    {
      id: 'weight',
      value: 'Weight',
    },
    {
      id: 'symbol',
      value: 'Symbol',
    }];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayedColumns = this.columnNames.map(x => x.id);
    this.createTable();
  }

  createTable() {
    let tableArr: Element[] = [{ position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
      { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
      { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
      { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
      { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
      { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
    ];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tableArr);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  position: number,
  name: string,
  weight: number,
  symbol: string
}
```

***app.module.ts***

```js
imports: [
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
],
```

Comment: Using this I can make reusable table component which takes data array and columnNames array. This is far better solution than examples in https://material.angular.io

Answer (score 224):

Remember to add `MatTableModule` in your `app.module's imports` i.e.

#### In Angular 9+

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'  

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatTableModule
    // ...
  ]
})
```

#### Less than Angular 9

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material'  

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatTableModule
    // ...
  ]
})
```

Comment: This one works for me, most tutorials use the table tag and not the mat-table tag.

Comment: This one works for me as well when you use the pagination also we have to do the same thing, I think

Comment: I had to make it `import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'; ` to work

Comment: 100%  @WasiF if you get a can't bind with angular material it mostly due to a module not being imported. The above answer gets my 100% support.

Answer (score 18):

- Angular Core v6.0.2,
- Angular Material, v6.0.2,
- Angular CLI v6.0.0 (globally v6.1.2)

I had this issue when running `ng test`, so to fix it, I added to my `xyz.component.spec.ts` file:

`import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';`

And added it to `imports` section in `TestBed.configureTestingModule({})`:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, MatTableModule ],
      declarations: [ BookComponent ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: Testing spec the answer here as well. Solved for Angular 7.

Comment: Thank you! So many questions on SO similar to this but yours is the only answer I found like this, problem was in .spec.ts for me as well.

Answer (score 13):

if your "import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';" is on a shared module, make sure you export it.

sharedmodule.ts:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material' 

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
    MatTableModule
    // ...
  ],
  exports:[ MatTableModule ]
})
```

then on your custom module where you define the component that use material table:

custommodule.ts:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [ sharedmodule ]     
})
```

Answer (score 10):

Material example is using the wrong table tags.
Change

```
<table mat-table></table>
<th mat-header-cell></th>
<td mat-cell></td>

<tr mat-header-row></tr>
<tr mat-row></tr>
```

to

```
<mat-table></mat-table>
<mat-header-cell></mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell></mat-cell>

<mat-header-row></<mat-header-row>
<mat-row></<mat-row>
```

Answer (score 9):

For Angular 7

Check where is your table component located. 
In my case it was located like app/shared/tablecomponent
where shared folder contains all sub components
But I was importing material module in Ngmodules of  app.module.ts which was incorrect. 
In this case Material module should be imported in Ngmodules of shared.module.ts 
And it works.

There is NO NEED to change 'table' to 'mat-table' in angular 7.

[Angular7 - Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53185437/angular7-cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-mat-ta?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6):

In my case the trouble was I didn't put the components that contain the datasource in the declarations of main module.

```
NgModule({
  imports: [
    EnterpriseConfigurationsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LegalCompanyTypeAssignComponent,
    LegalCompanyTypeAssignItemComponent,
    ProductsOfferedListComponent,
    ProductsOfferedItemComponent,
    CustomerCashWithdrawalRangeListComponent,
    CustomerCashWithdrawalRangeItemComponent,
    CustomerInitialAmountRangeListComponent,
    CustomerInitialAmountRangeItemComponent,
    CustomerAgeRangeListComponent,
    CustomerAgeRangeItemComponent,
    CustomerAccountCreditRangeListComponent, //<--This component contains the dataSource
    CustomerAccountCreditRangeItemComponent,
  

  ],
```

The component contains the dataSource:

export class CustomerAccountCreditRangeListComponent implements OnInit {

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set paginator(paginator: MatPaginator){
    this.dataSource.paginator = paginator;
  }
  @ViewChild(MatSort) set sort(sort: MatSort){
    this.dataSource.sort = sort;
  }

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(); //<--The dataSource used in HTML
  loading: any;
  resultsLength: any;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["id", "desde", "hasta", "tipoClienteNombre", "eliminar"];
  data: any;

  constructor(
    private crud: CustomerAccountCreditRangeService,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private ui: UIComponentsService
  ) {
  }
```

**This is for Angular 9**

Answer (score 4):

I imported MatTableModule in app-routing module and the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

I was also breaking my head for a long time with this error message and later I identified that I was using [datasource] instead of [dataSource].

Comment: Thanks for this! I had the same issue with a pug converter online from: https://html-to-pug.com/, it copied the **[dataSource]** input and converted it to **[datasource]**

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue!
Although I rectified it my adding the import of MatTableModule into the mycustom module.ts , instead of adding it in app.module.ts

Note: As I have created a custom module(inbox.module.ts) and created components in it, hence the declarations of those modules were created in inbox.module.ts, due to which the import of MatTableModule was suppose to be done in inbox.module.ts and not in app.module.ts

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was adding `MatTableModule` in the app module, but I have nested components like so:

```
app module
|__________dashboard module
           |_________________user module
                             |___________plans module
```

I added `MatTableModule` in the direct parent of plans module which is user module, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1 :** open ->  app.module.ts

**Step 2  :**  import below

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'
```

**Step 3:** And under import add **MatTableModule** as below

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     
   MatTableModule
    
  ]
})
```

Below is the screenshot to refer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who just use the Angular CDK and not Angular Material, instead of importing `MatTableModule` import `CdkTableModule`:

```
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';

@NgModule({
imports: [
    ...
    CdkTableModule,
    ...
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Once on my angular 13, I have got this same issue because I forgot to add my component in the app module in which I have imported MatTableModule.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was very strange, but I could reproduce it, which means it could happen to other people.

My Angular version was 14. When I wanted to add Material to my project with `ng add @angular/material` the material version it wanted to install, and asked me was **7.0.0** (which I missed and installed anyway).

When I had taken a look at other projects, their material version was much higher: **14.2.6**.

In the end what solved the issue for me was **giving a specific angular material version** for the `ng add` command. You'll have to check what your current version is and add that to the command. For example:

```
ng add @angular/material@14.2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to import the MatTableModule module and remove the [table element](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) show below for reference.
wrong implementation
`<table mat-table [dataSource]=”myDataArray”>
  ...
</table>`
correct implementation:
`<mat-table [dataSource]="myDataArray">
</mat-table>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your angular material version, I have the same, and I have resolved this when I have installed the good version of angular material in local.

Hope it solve yours too.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by change `[data-source]="dataSource"` to `[dataSource]="dataSource"` in my `name.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

I have separate modules for each feature and adding the feature module that contained the MatTableModule in the app.module has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Storybook, you need to ensure `MatTableModule` is imported in your stories `moduleMetadata`:

```
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [ModGridComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MatTableModule
      ]
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

If you've tried everything mentioned here and it didn't work, make sure you also have added angular material to your project. If not, just run the following command in the terminal to add it:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

After it successfully gets added, wait for the project to get refreshed, and the error will be automatically gone.

Answer (score -4):

Please see your dataSource varibale doesn't get the data from the server or dataSource is not assigned to the expected format of data.