# How can I implement a material table in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli-v6

I'm using Angular 6 and I want to add a responsive table with sort, filter and pagination. So I chose Material.

I'm trying to implement the basic example described in [the official documentation here](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/table/overview#getting-started).

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:

Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. ("

[here is a capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSbIz.png)

Here is my app.module.ts

```
import { MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatSortModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...
imports: [
BrowserModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatInputModule,
MatPaginatorModule,
MatProgressSpinnerModule,
MatSortModule,
MatTableModule,
...
]
```

Here is my ws-list.component.ts

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
];


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ws-list',
  templateUrl: './ws-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ws-list.component.css']
})

export class WorkspacesListComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight',     'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
```

And here is my ws-list.component.html:

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
</ng-container>

<!--<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>-->
<!--<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>-->
```

I checked the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228138/cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-table) but it's with Angular 5!

I add that these steps work well with angular 7. But I need Angular 6 version.

Any ideas to fix that, please?

Comment: Can you edit the code to share your code?

Comment: @A.Sana can your your code in `staclblitz`

Comment: Have your imported the appropriate module? `import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';`

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I added my code

Answer (score 1):

I found finally my error:

My component is under a **reusables** module: **app/reusables/components/ws-list**

I should import @angular/material in **reusables.module.tn** and not in **app.module.ts**

I hope that can help some one!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-material-table-example) demo of the table.

Here are some possible reasons for the error that I was able to reproduce:

> Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.

- You didn't install @angular/material or its dependencies (npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations --save)
- You didn't import it in your app module (add it to the imports array
- You haven't added the mat-table directive to your table

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did. I installed @angular/material and imported the module!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to import `MatTableModule` into your app.module.ts. You should also make sure you have added `"@angular/material": "^7.2.2"` to your package.json by means of an `ng add` or an `npm install` at the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but  "@angular/material": "^7.2.2", is added automatically to my package.json after install of @angular/material!

Answer (score 0):

material.module.ts:

```
....

        import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [..., MatTableModule],
        exports: [...,  MatTableModule]
    })
```