# Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. In angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, mat-table

using table of angular material shows above error to me, MatTableModule is imported in app module still it shows error. Is there any issue with array on datasource or with any importing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228138/cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-table)

Comment: Either add the mat-table directive to the table or use the mat-data-table component

Comment: after using mat-table to it now that error gone and now its shows error "Missing definitions for header and row, cannot determine which columns should be rendered."

Comment: Update your question with your code so that people may help.