# how can i fix this error Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-table'.

1. If 'mat-table' is an Angular component and it has 'dataSource' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

This is my app.component.html file

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" >

  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? toggleAllRows() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                    [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </tr>
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228138/cant-bind-to-datasource-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-table)

Answer (score 1):

I beleive the right way to do it is to add it in the .ts file

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new TablesDataSource(this.data);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add MatModule to the app.module.ts:

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'
```

And in the imports array of app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatTableModule <==
  ],
```

And then in you app.component.ts import below as follows:

```
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
```

Then it should work without an issue